# Is there a standard way to create a web request to a server to use applications on it?

Tags: c#, powershell, mono

I've been developing an application that interfaces with PowerShell for Windows. So far, everything has worked great. However, it connects to MySQL directly (I guess that's not good practice?) and also connects directly to the local PowerShell instance. My goal for the future, however is to make it cross platform. I currently purchased a book on cross platform development (mono based I believe) to get a handle on have a best practice common services layer for some basic things. However, I can't get my head around how I'll do that with PowerShell.

My question is, is there a way to host a server somewhere that accepts Powershell connections remotely via web requests from multiple connections at once? Otherwise, I don't see how I can port such an application to Android and the likes.

Also, I wouldn't be opposed to some basic links for best practices on web requests and the likes.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "web requests"? Please give an example.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I may be looking at the wrong terminology, but it seemed like a lot of people connect to their MySQL DB via SOAP commands and some kind of PHP script. I was wondering if there was some generic way to do that with applications in general, like PowerShell.

Comment: A lot of the powershell geeks (including myself) here might cringe a bit, but if you are going to do cross platform application development and administration I would recommend you stay away from proprietary technologies like powershell, and try to use things that are easily found on all platforms and standardized. This narrows the list of technologies significantly. THAT BEING SAID, you can totally rely on powershell for windows administration and scripting (at least for the time being, until msft kills it down the road)

Comment: @JakeHeidt Thanks for the response! The main purpose of my application is managing tasks in Office 365 with user created tasks. Long story short, unless there's an open way to manage Office 365 (I'm sure there's not), that won't help. :/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PowerShell Web Access](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-windows-powershell-web-access-in-windows-server-8-beta.aspx).

Comment: With Web Access, is there a way to turn that into a generic, public Powershell portal for multiple connections to hit? I don't expect a full walkthrough, but I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: He posted a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-windows-powershell-web-access-in-windows-server-8-beta.aspx)